# Why the newtype syntax creates a function

Tags: haskell, newtype

I look at this declaration:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }
```

Here is what I understand:

1) Parser  is declared as a type with a type parameter `a`

2) You can instantiate Parser by providing a parser function for example `p = Parser  (\s -> Nothing)`

What I observed is that suddenly I have a function name `parse` defined and it is capable of running Parsers.

For example, I can run:

```
parse (Parser  (\s -> Nothing)) "my input"
```

and get `Nothing` as output.

How was this parse function got defined with this specific signature? How does this function "know" to execute the Parser given to it? Hope that someone can clear my confusion.

Thanks!

Comment: it's the *record* syntax that creates an *accessor* function, automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }` you introduce three things:

1. A type named  `Parser`.
2. A term level constructor of `Parser`s named `Parser`. The type of this function is

```hs
Parser :: (String -> Maybe (a, String)) -> Parser a
```

You give it a function and it wraps it inside a `Parser`

3. A function named `parse` to remove the `Parser` wrapper and get your function back. The type of this function is:

```hs
parse :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (a, String)
```

Check yourself in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }
Prelude> :t Parser
Parser :: (String -> Maybe (a, String)) -> Parser a
Prelude> :t parse
parse :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (a, String)
Prelude>
```

It's worth nothing that the term level constructor (`Parser`) and the function to remove the wrapper (`parse`) are both arbitrary names and don't need to match the type name. It's common for instance to write:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { unParser :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }
```

this makes it clear `unParse` removes the wrapper around the parsing function. However, I recommend your type and constructor have the same name when using `newtypes`.

> How does this function "know" to execute the Parser given to it

You are unwrapping the function using `parse` and then calling the unwrapped function with `"myInput"`.

Answer (score 7):

First, let’s have a look at a parser newtype without record syntax:

```hs
newtype Parser' a = Parser' (String -> Maybe (a,String))
```

It should be obvious what this type does: it stores a function `String -> Maybe (a,String)`. To run this parser, we will need to make a new function:

```hs
runParser' :: Parser' a -> String -> Maybe (a,String)
runParser' (Parser' p) i = p i
```

And now we can run parsers like `runParser' (Parser' $ \s -> Nothing) "my input"`.

But now note that, since Haskell functions are curried, we can simply remove the reference to the input `i` to get:

```hs
runParser'' :: Parser' a -> (String -> Maybe (a,String))
runParser'' (Parser' p) = p
```

This function is exactly equivalent to `runParser'`, but you could think about it differently: instead of applying the parser function to the value explicitly, it simply takes a parser and fetches the parser function from it; however, thanks to currying, `runParser''` can still be used with two arguments.

Now, let’s go back to back to your original type:

```hs
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }
```

The only difference between your type and mine is that your type uses [record syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#Named_Fields_(Record_Syntax)), although it may be a bit hard to recognise since a `newtype` can only have one field; this record syntax automatically defines a function `parse :: Parser a -> (String -> Maybe (a,String))`, which extracts the `String -> Maybe (a,String)` function from the `Parser a`. Hopefully the rest should be obvious: thanks to currying, `parse` can be used with two arguments rather than one, and this simply has the effect of running the function stored within the `Parser a`. In other words, your definition is exactly equivalent to the following code:

```hs
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> Maybe (a,String))

parse :: Parser a -> (String -> Maybe (a,String))
parse (Parser p) = p
```